# Appended element not working with eq selector

Tags: jquery, append, selector

I have created a piece of script which is meant to collect a pages content, put it into a `div` tag off the page and then slide it in from the right, deleting the old `div` tag and then appending a new one to then repeat the process again once another page is selected.

JavaScript:

```
$(window).click(function() {
    $(".container:eq(1)").html("new stuff").slideDown(500, function() {
        $(".container:eq(0)").animate({
            width: "0px",
            opacity: 0
        }, 500, "", function() {
            $(this).remove();
            $(".container").parent().append('<div clas="container"></div>');
            $(".container:eq(1)").hide();
        });
    });
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="container">Test</div>
    <div class="container"></div>
</div>​
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVG8r/

When you click the page, it works fine the first time but every other time, I would expect the 'new stuff' to be shown again and the old 'new stuff' to slide away, introducing the new, 'new stuff'.  I have tested some alerts and the height of the new object is `null` so it doesn't exist.  I can see the new element in the HTML but it doesn't seem to be picked up by `$(".container:eq(1)")`.

Comment: `'<div clas="container"></div>'` should be `'<div class="container"></div>'`.

Comment: HAH! No way. That is it.

Comment: I thought I was onto some serious jQuery bug then..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mispelling of the attribute `class` in the appended HTML:

Change this:

```
$(".container").parent().append('<div clas="container"></div>');
```

to this:

```
$(".container").parent().append('<div class="container"></div>');
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/aeBrd/

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your code. In the line below:

```
$(".container").parent().append('<div clas="container"></div>');
```

`clas` as you know should be `class`. That makes it work as it should.